# React - Jest : No tests found, exiting with code 0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm learning ReactJS for a few weeks but I'm facing an issue that's impossible to solve by myself.

I use `create-react-app` command to start react project but it is totally impossible to use `npm test` after that. Even if I don't touch anything in the project, when I try to run `npm test` I only get "No tests found, exiting with code 0".... When I just create the project there is `src/App.test.js` but the command found nothing..... :(

Someone I sent the folder succeeded to run the tests.... is it possible that the problem comes from my computer/environment (Windows 10) ?

Thanks for help.

Have a good day

Comment: No, it isn't because of the operating system. Make sure `App.test.js` has at least one test. Make sure that you're running the command in the correct directory.

Comment: Do you have any Jest test cases written in the file?

Comment: Yes I wrote myself some basics tests then discovered that it didn't work.
So I restart from a new fully clean "create-react-app" with the original basic test that just include few lines

`import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});`

I run the `npm test` from the base directory "myTestApp" of the project (created with `create-react-app myTestApp`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

I found this posts https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7660 
wich explain that `npm test` don't work with hidden directories (.xxx).

My projet is under `C:\Users\kendr\.babun\cygwin\home\Kendrak\react\myprojet` 
The problem is the `.babun` !

I move my project in another dir and the test command now works fine!

Comment: It worked for me, even in a folder starting with a dot (.).


** test": "react-scripts test --watchAll --testMatch **/src/**/*.test.js **

Comment: I am so grateful to you. I wasted 2 hours trying to figure out why my tests wouldn't run. I had a folder with the name ".git".

Answer (score 14):

Add this line to your "package.json"

1. open package.json
2. find  scripts in that `"test" : "react scripts test"` replace this with

   ```
   "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll --testMatch **/src/**/*.test.js"
   ```
3. Now run npm test.

It works!

Comment: It worked for me, even in a folder starting with a dot (.).

"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll --testMatch **/src/**/*.test.js"

Answer (score 4):

If you are CRA(Create React App) user who is seeking proper answer, try this out in **package.json**.

`

```
{
  "name": "Your App",
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ]
  },
 "version": "0.1.0",
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

`

CRA manages jest in package.json. So if you use jest.configure.js in parent route you will get error about route something.
If you want another custom configuration give a change`testMatch`.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Kenkradstef, there can be issues with the path your project is in.
Had the same problem, with "[" "]" in my path. Full path was something like "`C:\Users\xxx\[P]rojects\xxx\`".

I moved the project to a different location and it worked.

Can't add a comment because I have no reputation, that's why I am posting this as an answer.