# React 18 with Husky pre-commit and jest - No tests found, exiting with code 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, husky

After going down the rabbit-hole, this is as far as I seem to be able to get. I've got my husky pre-commit hook "working", but it's not finding tests when there clearly is a test, and it appears to be looking in the correct folder for it.

This is all cobbled together from searching and troubleshooting, just to get to the point where jest wouldn't simply hang and do nothing.

React 18 via create-react-app. Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-web-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
            "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./src",
        "lint:fix": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./src --fix",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "husky": "^8.0.3"
    }
}
```

In the root of `my-web-app`, I've got this:

[image]

Here's `logging.test.js`:

```
const TIMEOUT = (5 * 60) * 1000;

beforeAll(done => {
    done();
});
beforeEach((done) => {
    done();
});
afterEach((done) => {
    done();
});
afterAll(() => {
});

test("Fake test", async () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
}, TIMEOUT);
```

`setupTests.test.js`:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

`pre-commit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run lint && npm run test
```

Here's the entirety of my output when trying to commit:

```
> my-web-app@0.1.0 lint
> eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./src


> my-web-app@0.1.0 test
> react-scripts test --watchAll=false

No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/me/projects/my-web-app
  3 files checked.
  testMatch: /Users/me/projects/my-web-app/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, /Users/me/projects/my-web-app/src/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, /Users/me/projects/my-web-app/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx} - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 3 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

How is `testMatch: /Users/me/projects/my-web-app/**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` not finding the fake test in my `__tests__` folder? Even hard-coding the path yields the same result. I must be doing something dumb.

Comment: Is this anything to do with Husky - do you get different results when you run `npm t` directly? Presumably the pattern's not quite right - why not restore Jest's default testMatch (see  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring), which would cover your files?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Default behavior causes a hang on commit, which led me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718606/react-scripts-and-jest-no-tests-found-on-running-npm-test

Then, upon doing the recommended, I was able to get jest to actually run properly, which led me to the current issue that I'm asking about. This is what I found and tried...which gave me the result above, and where I'm at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671746/1167996

Comment: I mean use _Jest's_ default values, as linked to, rather than CRA's (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#filename-conventions).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got it. I removed the "jest" section I added to package.json and just moved the `__tests__` folder to /src, and it ran the test. I had to keep `--watchAll=false` in place on the npm command or it hangs w/ no tests found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. In the end, I just needed to move the `__tests__` folder into the `/src` folder. This negated the need for the "jest" section in package.json. It will still hang with no tests found unless I use the `--watchAll=false` option on the npm command, like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./src --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install"
}
```